# Javascript: Disable Radio buttons by selecting value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to use radio buttons for making the appointment in a PHP web app.

I have a list of Radio Buttons as below, the user can select any of this radio button and its value stored in the database on be half of the appointment date and time.

```
<tr>
 <td>
     <label><input type="radio" name="book" value="1" required>11.00 AM</label>
 </td>
 <td>
    <label><input type="radio" name="book" value="2" required>11.10 AM</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <label><input type="radio" name="book" value="3" required>11.20 AM</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <label><input type="radio" name="book" value="4" required>11.30 AM</label>
 </td>
 <td>
     <label><input type="radio" name="book" value="5" required>11.40 AM</label>
 </td>
 <td>
    <label><input type="radio" name="book" value="6" required>11.50 AM</label>
 </td>
 <td>
      <label><input type="radio" name="book" value="7" required>12.00 PM</label>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Also I want to disable the radio buttons which are already selected and stored in the database.

So on page load, i am getting previously stored radio button values using AJAX as below,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'http://localhost/design-ci/booking/abc',
        dataType    : 'json',
        encode      : true
    });
});
```

and this reruns/response an array as below which contains radio button values that stored in the database,(I hope the coding for "http://localhost/design-ci/booking/abc" function/action is no need for this)

```
[{"value":"1"},{"value":"4"},{"value":"6"}]
```

and my question is how to disable the radio buttons which contains in the array.
The values in the array are the values which previous users selected and stored in the database and the current users cannot select them as they are booked already.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need complete code?

Comment: Just a tip, the link to localhost isn't going to work on any other PC apart from yours..

Comment: Why do you need to load it with AJAX? Is there any reason why you cannot load booked terms while generating the page?

Comment: I have hundreds of radio buttons which cannot print using foreach loop in php.

Answer (score 0):

**Let me explain simply:**

1) Get existing values from database. In your case 1, 4, 6.

2) Create an array of time slots as mentioned below.

3) Loop over the array and print the checkboxes.

4) If value is present in existing values, add `disabled` attribute, else, nothing.

```
<?php
$existingValues = array(1, 4, 6);
$timeSlots = array();
$timeSlots[1] = '11.00 AM';
$timeSlots[2] = '11.10 AM';
$timeSlots[3] = '11.20 AM';
$timeSlots[4] = '11.30 AM';
$timeSlots[5] = '11.40 AM';
$timeSlots[6] = '11.50 AM';
$timeSlots[7] = '12.00 AM';
if (! empty($timeSlots)) {
?>
<tr>
<?php
  foreach ($timeSlots as $val => $display) {
    $disabled = in_array($val, $existingValues) ? 'disabled' : '';
?>
<td><label><input type="radio" name="book" value="<?php echo $val;?>" required <?php echo $disabled;?>><?php echo $display;?></label></td>
<?php
  }
?>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

[Reference of disabled](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls:-the-disabled-attribute)

Comment: Thanks for this. But I am looking to do this in Java scripts because the array contains 1, 4, 6 is an AJAX response.

Answer (score 0):

> Also I want to disable the radio buttons which are already selected and stored in the database.

Do this directly from PHP,maybe in a separate file which you then include?Something like this,pseudo code..

```
<?php
$age = array("1"=>"0", "2"=>"1", "3"=>"0");

for loop  with array length
 if(key value==0)
  print radio button with checkbox enabled
 else
  print radio button with checkbox disabled

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to do this using java-script one simple way to do this, is use fetching element property of java-script
add id="some distinct name for each label not same as name are!" to your html code along with your name="book"
use:

document.getElementById("idname").disabled = true;

this will disable the radio buttons associated with the corresponding id.
so, whichever radio buttons are already booked u can fetch them form your db or maintain a log to disable the list of radio buttons just by iterating them in a loop